# How to choose which camera is used by Nvidia-Geforce Overlay?

Tags: nvidia-geforce, camera, nvidia-settings

I recently added a new camera to my setup and would like to keep both, but now I want to use my new camera with nvidia-geforce to record myself. However, I can't find any way to tell the software which camera to use to record me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvidia geforce shadowplay overlay will use the default webcam. Go to Control Panel > Devices and Printer > Check if the webcam is listed and then right-click and set as default.

Another way, go to device manager > imaging devices and disable all other webcams except this

Comment: What if there's no option to set as default? This is what I get https://imgur.com/a/kcTw9N2

Comment: Another way, go to device manager > imaging devices and disable all other webcams except this

Comment: okay, this worked, but I couldn't find my other camera under imaging devices. Instead I found it in a section lower in the list called "sound, video and game controllers"

Comment: @Keyboard Hunter did that work

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia will use default webcam on overlay. From control panel devices and printers check for the webcam listed then right click and set as default